# C standard library/function to find the byte order of the hardware

Tags: c

I know there are very many different non-standard ways of finding (and converting) the endianness of your hardware. For example, [here](http://www.intel.com/design/intarch/papers/endian.pdf) is one!

We have the standard functions like `htonl()`, `htons()`, `ntohl()` and `ntohs()` to convert values between host and network byte order.

Now my question is, in analogous to the above mentioned standard macros, are there any *standard* C macros/functions that is available to find the byte order of the hardware?

Comment: Depending on your definition of "standard C library": if (htons(i)==i) ...

Comment: `htonl` are not C standard functions. Please specify in which standard you are interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Endianness is a feature of the platform that is often known at compile time. `htonl()`, `htons()`, `ntohl()` and `ntohs()` are not always *functions*: they may be *macros* that use conditional compile to perform their "magic". In order for them to work, sometimes either `BIG_ENDIAN` or `LITTLE_ENDIAN` is `#define`d (but not both), (**edit2**) or in other implementations both BIG_ENDIAN and LITTLE_ENDIAN are set to different values, and also a BYTE_ORDER is defined to be equal to one or the other. You can examine the values of these definitions to find out the endian-ness of your platform at compile time; the way you do that would depend on your implementation, though.

**Edit1** If your platform implements endianness functions as functions, not as macros, you could use any of these functions to see if it converts `1` to itself. If it does, then your hardware is big-endian.

P.S. Special thanks to CharlesBailey for his observation on the initial edit of my answer.

Comment: No, `htonl`, `htons`, `ntohl` and `ntohs` are _functions_ as specified in POSIX.1-2001. If your implementation provides masking macros for these then this is an optional optimization.

Comment: @CharlesBailey Thanks for clarifications! I was under the impression that `htonl` etc. were always macros, but I see that I was wrong. I clarified my answer. Thanks!

Comment: In what sense is this an answer? The C standard has nothing of these endian macros. Where do they come from?

Comment: @JensGustedt These functions/macros are in the [POSIX.1-2001](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl) standard.

Comment: So how does this answer the question, as far as I can see it only relates to C. And your link refers to `htonl` etc, where do `BIG_ENDIAN` and `LITTLE_ENDIAN` come from?

Comment: @JensGustedt The OP refers to htonl(), htons(), ntohl() and ntohs() as standard, so he does not insist on functionality only from the C standard. The OP said that he was looking for "any *standard* C macros/functions", not "any *C standard* macros/functions", so I think this is a reasonable answer to the question (and it looks like the OP thinks so too :)

Comment: Still you don't answer my question. Where do BIG_ENDIAN and LITTLE_ENDIAN come from? I don't see them mentioned in POSIX. That the OP is satisfied only means that by coincidence he is on a similar system than yours.

Comment: The only thing that I found is this link http://www.opengroup.org/austin/docs/austin_512.txt, which just indicates that these macros are not (yet) standard.

Comment: BIG_ENDIAN and LITTLE_ENDIAN are found in Glibc’s endian.h (and perhaps some other implementations?), where they are either both defined or neither defined.  You compare BYTE_ORDER with one or the other (or PDP_ENDIAN) to discover the target byte order.

Comment: @RichardKettlewell Others comments have made it abundantly clear that it's implementation dependent: on AIX they define one or the other; on your system both are defined. I edited my answer in response to these comments.

Comment: Which version of AIX? Here it has the same logic as Glibc, albeit in sys/machine.h rather than endian.h.  In fact the commentary is sufficiently similar that I suspect common ancestry.

Answer (score 7):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int little_endian(){
    int x = 1;
    return *(char*)&x;
}
int big_endian(){
    return !little_endian();
}

int main(){
    if(big_endian())
        printf("big_endian\n");
    if(little_endian())
        printf("little_endian\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ha!  My Commodore 64 was little endian.  :)

Comment: it's 8bit machine, need other way.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Is there any compile time alternative?

Comment: may be macros .

Answer (score 2):

How about `htonl(100) == 100` ?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

```
#include <endian.h>
#if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN
#elif __BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN
#elif __BYTE_ORDER == __PDP_ENDIAN
#else
#error "no byte order"
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

You could store a known value and then inspect the resulting bytes to learn about the representation, and remain within the confines of Standard C.

Tests such as htonl(n)==n can only work if you assume that little-endian and big-endian are the only choices - for a counterexample see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Middle-endian

As far as I know endian.h has not been written into any standard (which is a shame).  It’s not even present on all Unix platforms.